# How to clean an all-clad stainless steel pan

Tags: cleaning, cookware

I accidentally left one of my all-clad stainless steel saucepans on the stove & the water in it boiled off... I used Bar Keeper's Friend(BKF) & I was able to remove all the spots in the interior of the pan but the shiny finish on the exterior is yellowed now and BKF did not remove this stain.
It almost looks like when sterling silver starts to tarnish.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Brillo/S.O.S pads (the real metal ones) and Barkeepers Friend.Recently I found a liquid Barkeepers Friend that works well also.

Use the Barkeepers Friend first or just trade off.  Brillo/S.O.S last.

There has never been crud or discoloration that has survived these two products. There have never been scratches with Brillo/S.O.S on my stainless steel both inside and out All Clad.

I think that Brillo/S.O.S works to really put a shine on the interior of the pan.  Eggs do just slide around.  Not too shabby.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a really bad stain you can use steel wool. It may leave some scratch marks, but that just means you use your pan!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The stain is not that bad actually, I think I just ruined the finish due to overheating an empty pan! Not a big deal, life goes on...

Answer (score 0):

Get as much of the burnt black little parts off of it as possible. Put bread around the top of it and remove when it is seared. Finally put in peeled potatoes, then put it in the fridge to cool off. It works very well.

Comment: Brenda, did you read the question carefully? The original question dealt with removing yellowish discoloration *from the outside* of the pan - whatever you put *inside* probably won't help much.

Answer (score 0):

Polish it with 'Brasso' or some other metal polish that is acidic and claims to work on stainless. This isn't the only way to get that off, but it's easiest.